# How do I export an Oracle database (into a single file) and install it on a client machine without installing an Oracle software (like Oracle server)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a windows desktop application ( point of sales) using Delphi for the software and i want to use oracle for the database part, so I have installed "Oracle Database XE program " on my dev machine, i will work on the default XE pluggable database ( create my tables and functions) and to connect to the database from Delphi using UniDAC , so when i finish my application i want to deliver it to a client ,this client has only one machine and has no access to any network . so is there a way to export the oracle database in to a single file and then copy that file to the application folder and connect to the file using the UniDAC so when i deliver the application to the client i will install only my application so i do not have to install the "Oracle Database XE program".

so is there a way to export the oracle database in to a single file and then copy that file to the application folder and connect to the file using the UniDAC so when i deliver the application to the client i will install only my application so i do not have to install the "Oracle Database XE program".

Comment: A database is a data stored in files. DBMS is, how you may guess by the name, is a software that **manages** this data: provides an access to it, handles creation of new objects, handles constraints, handles connections and security. What do you want to do with a data without a software to access it? And why do you choose an Oracle as a local database instead of more common SQLite, for example, that has a very little bundle and is designed to be used as a local database?

Comment: i do not want to use SQLite because it does not provide "stored procedures" concept, i only need to create a setup file that has all the component so the client only installs the setup file.

Comment: Single file distribution is not possible, with *any* RDBMS that I am familiar with. Installation of a database server is required; proprietary file formats cannot be manipulated or stored procedures run without the actual database kernel making the changes or executing the code. Data files are not themselves executable.

Answer (score 0):

That won't work, in my opinion. You *can* export that schema (see Data Pump utility, both Export and Import) and get a .dmp file, but it is to be imported into target database.

If your application requires Oracle database, how do you plan to make it work on your customer's computer *without* a database? As Express Edition (XE) is free to use, why wouldn't you (or customer) install that database so that they would use that application without any problems?

Comment: the costumer does not know anything about the databases, he only knows "double click, next,finish" that is why i only need to create a setup file that has all the component so the client only installs the setup file.

Answer (score 0):

[Silent installation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/xeinw/installing-oracle-database-xe.html#GUID-E6A7B665-134B-4EF3-AB78-A33A54908EB9) still requires installing the database on the customer's computer, but it can be done without any customer input. All of the configuration options can be chosen ahead of time via a configuration file and command line arguments.

And I'm sure you can combine the silent installation with one of the many Windows installers to build a single .EXE that will unzip the Oracle setup files, run the `setup.exe` command, install the Delphi pieces, etc.